# JSON to Array Bash

Tags: linux, json, bash, curl

Есть curl, получаю json.
Теперь нужно его обработать и выполнить некие команды.
Как превратить его в массив?

```
VAR=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/ | python -m json.tool)
echo "${VAR}"
```

Как-то так получаю всё-равно json

Пробую. Говорит нет файла JSON

```
json=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/)
array=( $(jq -r '.[].worker_id' json))
```

Пробую с файлом. Работает.

```
echo $(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/) > $dir/my.json
gpio=( `jq '.[].gpio' $dir/my.json`)
command=( `jq '.[].journal.command' $dir/my.json`)
```

Но имею

**jq: error: Cannot index array with string
jq: error: Cannot index array with string**

Comment: Так питон или баш? Для парсинга json на bash нужно пакет `jq` поставить.

Comment: Окей, я поставил @don-rumata jq поставил. Теперь не понятно как загнать это в переменную.

Comment: Ну без сорца - хз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/) > $dir/my.json
gpios=( `jq '.[].gpio' $dir/my.json`)
command=( `jq '.[].journal[0].command' $dir/my.json`)
```